# Parse MDT Log using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parsing, logging

I am trying to setup a log which would pull different information from another log file to log assets build by MDT using PowerShell. I can extract a line of log using simple `get-content | select-string` to get the lines i need so output looks like that

> [LOG[Validate Domain Credentials [domain\user]]LOG]!
>   time="16:55:42.000+000" date="10-20-2017" component="Wizard"
>   context="" type="1" thread="" file="Wizard"

and I am curious if there is a way of capturing things like domain\user, time and date in a separate variables so it can be later passed with another data captured in a similar way  in output file in a single line.

Comment: Why is anything running as a domain user during a MDT buildout?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: because it joins it to the domain on build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
$line = Get-Content "<your_log_path>" | Select-String "Validate Domain Credentials" | select -First 1
$regex = '\[(?<domain>[^\\[]+)\\(?<user>[^]]+)\].*time="(?<time>[^"]*)".*date="(?<date>[^"]*)".*component="(?<component>[^"]*)".*context="(?<context>[^"]*)".*type="(?<type>[^"]*)".*thread="(?<thread>[^"]*)".*file="(?<file>[^"]*)"'
if ($line -match $regex) {
    $user = $Matches.user
    $date = $Matches.date
    $time = $Matches.time
    # ... now do stuff with your variables ...
}
```

You might want to build in some error checking etc. (e.g. when no line is found or does not match etc.)

Also you could greatly simplify the regex if you only need those 3 values. I designed it so that all fields from the line are included.

Also, you could convert the values into more appropriate types, which (depending on what you want to do with them afterwards) might make handling them easier:

```
$type = [int]$Matches.type
$credential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Matches.user, $null, $Matches.domain)
$datetime = [DateTime]::ParseExact(($Matches.date + $Matches.time), "MM-dd-yyyyHH:mm:ss.fff+000", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you, not quite what I was looking for but you gave me an idea

Comment: @104r Feel free to tell me what else you need and I'm happy to help.

Comment: so I am working on BDD.log which is massive file but only few lines from that file are of my interest. So I  get the line which I want using get-content <mylogfile> | select-string "Validate Domain Credentials " (probably not the best way but i get the line I want ) and the line comes as above. Now I like how you did that query which makes $matches variable and wanted to use that to make $user, $time, $date variables using something similar so at the end i can pass it to another log file using those along other details. One thing which i need to get is what this string means before word domain

Comment: @104r I've edited my answer. Hope that is more like what you want.

Comment: Many thanks @marsze this is exactly what I wanted. Proper Powershell Magician you are.   I appreciate your help.   I just wanted to pass them to another log file along with make/model  and serial number of computer being build.